# Can we correct, improvise and/or optimize this solution to a common SQL: Displays two oldest employees in each department of an organization

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Below, created a (SQL server table variable) schema, inserted dummy data (for testing) and attempted to write a query to display two (replaceable by N) employees from every department who has stayed with the company longest. Can someone please help in improving, correcting and/or optimizing this solution. (feel free to execute the code in SQL management studio as-it-is to run to execute and see results if needed)

```
    --declare employee variable to hold employee data
    DECLARE @employee TABLE
    (
        id int,     
        name varchar(50), 
        startdate datetime, 
        enddate datetime, 
        departmentid int
    )

    --declare department variable to hold department data
    DECLARE @department TABLE
    (
        id int, 
        name varchar(50)
    )

    --insert dummy department data
    INSERT INTO @department VALUES (1, 'IT'),
                                   (2, 'SALES'),
                                   (3, 'HR')

    --insert dummy employee data
    INSERT INTO @employee VALUES (1, 'mikhail', '01/01/2005', '01/01/2013', 1),
                              (2, 'david', '01/01/2006', '01/01/2012', 1),
                              (3, 'andrew', '01/01/2002', null, 1),
                              (4, 'will', '01/01/2013', null, 1),
                              (5, 'dave', '01/01/2006', '01/01/2012', 2),
                              (6, 'mike', '01/01/2002', '01/01/2012', 2),
                              (7, 'brad', '01/01/2011', null, 2),
                              (8, 'thomas', '01/01/2002', '01/01/2003', 3),
                              (9, 'anthony', '01/01/2015', null, 3),
                              (10, 'vincent', '01/01/2002', null, 3),
                              (11, 'bobby', '01/01/2002', '01/01/2003', 3);

    --declare variable to old intermediate data
    DECLARE @hold TABLE (rowid int, ename varchar(50), timew int, dname varchar(50))

    -- insert intermediate data
    INSERT INTO @hold
        SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dname ORDER BY timew DESC) rowid, ename, timew, dname
        FROM
        (
            SELECT E.name ename, E.startdate startdate, E.enddate enddate, 
            CASE
                WHEN E.enddate is null then datediff(DAY, E.startdate, getdate())
                ELSE datediff(DAY, E.startdate, E.enddate)
            END timew, D.name dname
            FROM @employee E inner join @department D ON E.departmentid = D.id
        ) PART

    -- final result
    SELECT ename, dname FROM @hold WHERE rowid < 3
```

Comment: Why?   What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine some of the logic and make the query smaller but other than that you seem to have a good understanding of how it should be done.

```
SELECT ename, dname
FROM
(   
    SELECT  e.name ename,
            d.name dname,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.name ORDER BY datediff(DAY, E.startdate, COALESCE(e.enddate, getdate())) desc) rn
    FROM    @employee e
            INNER JOIN @department d ON e.departmentid = d.id
) t
WHERE rn < 3
```

One thing I might suggest would be to consider using DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER if you want to include ties

```
SELECT ename, dname
FROM
(   
    SELECT  e.name ename,
            d.name dname,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY d.name ORDER BY datediff(DAY, E.startdate, COALESCE(e.enddate, getdate())) desc) rnk
    FROM    @employee e
            INNER JOIN @department d ON e.departmentid = d.id
) t
WHERE rnk < 3
```

More information on [**Ranking Functions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jamie, for improvising.